# How to merge result of 2 PHP script outputs

Tags: php, curl

I am getting only the result for the first script. But I want the response for both PHP scripts to be in one output. In my program I am developing, I am querying several remote servers. I have to search information on different servers and return the result in one response.

```
<?php
    // build the individual requests as above, but do not execute them
    $ch_1 = curl_init('http://lifesaver.netai.net/example/pharm.php');
    $ch_2 = curl_init('http://192.168.1.2/example/pharm.php');
    curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=$value");
    curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=$value");

    // $_POST["name"]

    // build the multi-curl handle, adding both $ch
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch_1);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch_2);

    // execute all queries simultaneously, and continue when all are complete
    $running = null;
    do {
      curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running);

    // all of our requests are done, we can now access the results
    $response_1 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_1);
    $response_2 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_2);

    echo $response_1;
    echo $response_2;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [`curl_multi_getcontent`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-getcontent.php), you need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` instead of `false`.

Also, the documentation of [`curl_multi_init`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) shows an example which is slightly different than yours when it comes to the execution loop:

```
//execute the handles
$running = null;
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($running && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
```

You could try it that way.